# On ubuntu 21.10 the "lock screen on suspend" not working anymore

Tags: lock-screen

Since I updated from ubuntu 21.04 to ubuntu 21.10 the suspend still works but there is no password required anymore when the laptop awakes out of suspend. I did not change any settings and I still see "lock screen on suspend" = YES in the settings. How do I solve that?

Comment: as 21.10 is an interim release it might be best to [report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug/?no-redirect)

Comment: Ok, I did. Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm what "lock screen on suspend" is supposed to mean? I am having trouble interpreting it. When suspend the computer is off, so do they mean "YES lock the screen when coming out of suspend?"